# MQ error 2102(Resource_Prob in datastage)

Tags: ibm-mq

When datastage Job is trying to put the message in queue, The error message comes, I guess this may be the issue with size of file which we were trying to post, which were around 3MB, but when we tried with around 2MB size, it got posted succesfuly in the queue.
Can somebody guide on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQ error 2102 indicates "insufficient system resources to complete the call successfully".

As per your question, you get this error when you post bigger message.

So, it makes me believe that your server is running out of space which is causing this issue.